# Make rectangle width fill ScrollView

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I'm trying to get something in a `ScrollView` to expand in `width` to fit the screen. The `ScrollView` is anchored to the main window.

For example purposes, a `Rectangle`:

```
ScrollView {
    anchors.fill: parent //mainWindow
    Rectangle {
        color: "light grey"
        height: 1000
        width: mainWindow.width
    }
}
```

But when the vertical scrollbar appears, it obscures the `Rectangle`. I can sort of fix it by using a magic constant:

```
width: mainWindow.width - 20
```

But what if somebody has bigger scrollbars on their computer? Also it leaves an ugly empty space on the right when the vertical scrollbar is invisible.

Is there a way to automatically learn what the available space is inside of a `ScrollView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly adjust to scroll bar. You can just make it to fill the entire available parent space or so. And if you want specify margins:

```
ScrollView {
    id: scrollView
    anchors.fill: parent // mainWindow ?
    anchors.centerIn: parent // anchoring as asked
    anchors.margins: 20

    contentItem:
        Rectangle {
        id: rectScroll
        width: scrollView.viewport.width  // set as viewport
        height: 1000 // set to what you need
    }
}
```

The original issue was solved mainly due to the `width` property of `Rectangle` set to `parent.parent.width` or `scrollView.viewport.width` as it is more adequate. The latter is definitely better, as long as the `width` of precisely viewport of scroll area and not the parent `width` (which in general not guaranteed to contain only this `ScrollView`).